# projection of empty fields in mongodb aggregation

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I am using aggregation to find a result from MongoDB using following query.

```
$y=2000;
$project['pud_year']=array('$year'=>'$pud');
$conditions=array('aggregate'=>array(       
                        array('$match'=>array('pid'=>$project_id)),
                        array('$project'=>$project),
                        array('$match'=>array('pud'=>$y)),
                        ));
$this->paginate=array('limit' => 50,'conditions'=>$conditions);
$test=$this->paginate();
```

But I am getting the error `can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date` .

After searching I have found that in aggregation, projected date field must not be empty at any place in complete collection. But in my case `pud` is not compulsory. When I remove projection of pud from query it works fine.

If I am not doing projection of MongoDate into `$year` then I am unable to fetch the results only for year 2000.

Please help me figuring out solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $ifNull i believe. This will give you an option to return a default date when the $pud is null. It works well with aggregation. Please check this -- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: checking it. then let you know

Comment: `array('$project' => 
array("pud_year"=> 
array('$year' => 
array('$ifNull'=>
array('$pud',nullFieldDt)))))` - you could construct the `ifNull` construct this way. Where `nullFieldDt` is the default value for the field for the records without the date field.

Comment: I am using it like `$project['pud_year'] = array('$year' => array('$ifNull'=> array('$pud',nullFieldDt)));` But it is giving error `the $year operator does not accept an object as an operand`

Comment: @BatScream Its not working. Is there any problem in `$project['pud_year'] = array('$year' => array('$ifNull'=> array('$pud',nullFieldDt)));`

Comment: You should initialize  'nullfielddt' variable to some dummy date you do not want to match. Such as, var 'nullfielddt'=new Date();

Comment: declaring `nullFieldDt` as date is also proucing same error. Or I need to format date in some specific format?